# Get user info using Graph API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am getting below error when I try to fetch the user information through access-token.
My Angular application has below flow (Web API that calls web APIs)

Angular application --> pass autorizecode --> API (generate access-token) --- > Graph API (User api)

> One or more errors occurred. (OnBehalfOfCredential authentication
> failed: AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason -
> Key was found, but use of the key to verify the signature failed.,
> Thumbprint of key used by client:
> 'F8A23743D9CD47B6D1A1FXXXXXXA17A9B1D919EC', Found key
> 'Start=10/02/2022 18:06:49, End=10/02/2027 18:06:49']. Trace ID:
> 1d326676-f8a5-4410-b4cf-SSS1a9b64800 Correlation ID:
> 79ca8aec-bb73-48f9-b0d2-XXXb4226e625 Timestamp: 2023-03-10 10:22:27Z)

Application has below scope in Azure

```
 "openid", "profile", "User.Read.All"
```

```
                var tenantId= "tenantid";
                var clientId= "clientid";
                var clientSecret = "secret";

                // using Azure.Identity;
                var options = new OnBehalfOfCredentialOptions
                {
                    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
                };

                // This is the incoming token to exchange using on-behalf-of flow
                var oboToken = accessToken;

                var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, oboToken, options);
                
                GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential, scopes);
                
                var result = graphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                {
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Count = true;
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Search = "\"displayName:rock\"";
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string[] { "displayName" };
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "displayName", "mail" };
                    requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");

                }).Result;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if you are passing invalid assertion while generating access token.

- Check if the scope you are passing is valid.
- Make sure that the access token (assertion) is not expired.

**To resolve the error**, try the below:

For sample, I created **`Server`** Azure AD Application and Exposed an API, added Authorized client applications:

[image]

Now, In **`Client`** Application I added the API permissions like below:

[image]

Now I generated access token to pass in assertion using **Authorization Code Flow** like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <client_app_ID>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: api://<API_app_ID>/test.read
code: code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
client_secret: <secret>
```

[image]

Now I generated access token using **`on-behalf-of`** flow by using **scope** as `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All`

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <API_app_ID>
client_secret: <API_app_secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion: <paste_token_from_above_request>
requested_token_use: on_behalf_of
```

[image]

**Note** that: To get user profile the **`aud`** should be `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

When I decoded the token, **`aud`** is Microsoft Graph like below:

[image]

When I used the above generated access token, **I am able to fetch the user profile successfully** like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID
```

[image]

You can also make use of **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`** scope while generating access token in  **`on-behalf-of`**  flow.

To resolve the error, make changes in the code like below:

```cs
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All" };
var tenantId = "TenantID";
var clientId = "ClientID";
var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";

var options = new OnBehalfOfCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};
var oboToken = "JWTToken";
var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, oboToken, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential,scopes);

var result = graphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Count = true; 
                 requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Search = "\"displayName:rock\"";  
                 requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string[] { "displayName" };  
                 requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "displayName", "mail" };    
                 requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");
}).Result;
```

And make sure to generate access token for passing it as assertion with proper scopes.

**References:**

[Choose-authentication-providers.md at main · microsoftgraph · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/concepts/sdks/choose-authentication-providers.md#c-2) by andrueastman

[GitHub Web API calling a downstream API on behalf of the user](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof) by neha-bhargava